# Add/remove listeners on JavaScript ( garbage collector )

Tags: javascript, memory-management, dom-events

I have a quick question regarding on adding/removing listeners of a DOM object.
I would like to ask if the garbage collector be able to collect the memory when removing elements from the page.

Example: a `<ul>` tag with a couple list of children(`<li>`)

```
var ul = document.getElementById('someParent');
var children = ul.children;
var someFunction = function() {};

for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  children[i].addEventListener('click', someFunction);
}


// This is where I am not sure, would the garbage collector be able to collect
// the memory allocated on adding listener on children,
// if I remove the ul tag?
ul.remove();
```

Comment: Your loop won't work correctly. `children.length` is not good condition.

Comment: just a typo, will edit it thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `ul.remove();` will remove `ul` element and all of its children from the DOM. But memory for event listeners will not be released as long as you have references to those listeners, `li` elements, and `ul` element. Which you do have in variables `children`, `someFunction` and `ul`.

If you want to let the garbage collector clean all of these, you can do for example:

```
ul.remove();
children = null;
someFunction = null;
ul = null;
```

That way variable `children` will not hold the reference to those elements, and if you don't have any other variable in your code that hold the reference for those elements, garbage collector will collect them. The same holds for `someFunction`. Note that `ul` element holds all the references to its children and listeners, so `ul` has to be cleaned as well.

Comment: I see, that's makes sense. If it's an anonymous function it will be alright right?

Comment: Yes, for anonymous function it will be alright. Just make sure that `children` are also clean.

Comment: I see, I have an itch in the back of my mind before this and not it's gone. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: `Element.children` is a live list, though, so I don't believe it would continue to contain a reference to the elements after they are removed from the DOM. I can't find any references for this, though, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @lonesomeday, I assume your `Element` is `ul` in the example. `ul.children` is a live list indeed. But that means if you remove some child of `ul` element from the DOM, it will be reflected in that list. But if you remove `ul` from the DOM (as in the example), that list will remain intact.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all, you can access to the ul variable somewhere else. The example below showing that.

```
var ul = document.getElementById('someParent');
ul.remove();
console.log(ul); // ul and all li tags
document.body.appendChild(ul); // ul appears again
```

The example is not a normal case. The normal case is that you want to access a DOM reference in an event say "button click". That reference will be always available as long as the event isn't unbind. For example:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('someParent');
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
myButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    ul.innerHTML += '<li>Some text</li>'
});
ul.remove();
myButton.click(); // no exception when execting button click event
```

To avoid memory leak in JS:

1. make sure that there are no DOM references by using jQuery for
   example.
2. if you use DOM references in you application, set them to null or
   undefined when they are not in use.

So you can modify your event a little bit as below.

```
myButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // check ul belongs to visible DOM
    if (!document.body.contains(ul)) {
        ul = null;
        return;
    }
    ul.innerHTML += '<li>Some text</li>'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone can confirm this for me I'd appreciate it.

From my understanding, **yes** it will be garbage collected. According to [MDN Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

> The main notion garbage collection algorithms rely on is the notion of reference. Within the context of memory management, an object is said to reference another object if the former has an access to the latter (either implicitly or explicitly). For instance, a JavaScript object has a reference to its prototype (implicit reference) and to its properties values (explicit reference).

Essentially if the DOM cannot find a reference to said element, it will garbage collect it sometime in the near future. Looking at the DOM Standard specification of how [.remove()](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-remove) works, it will run a series of steps that will set the new indexes of parents and siblings removing all references to the element.

Because there are no references to said element, it will be garbage collected. In your example, you are adding eventListeners only to the children of the specific `<ul>` element you created. When you remove an element, you also remove all references of its children as well (I think this is clearer in the steps in the link above where they actually set the parent index to point to itself).

EDIT: @contrabit is right though. I didn't see you stored your `children` in a variable. As long as their is a reference to them, they won't be garbage collected.